# PySchools topic 3 Q8

Tags: python

The question is

> For a quadratic equation in the form of ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c, the
>   discriminant, D is b<sup>2</sup>-4ac.
>       Write a function that return the following output depending on the discriminant.
>
> - D > 0: 2 real roots.
> - D = 0: 1 real root.
> - D < 0: 2 complex roots.
>
> Examples
>
> ```
> >>> quadratic(1, 2, 3)
>     'This equation has 2 complex roots.'
> >>> quadratic(1, 3, 2)
>     'This equation has 2 real roots.'
> >>> quadratic(1, 4, 4)
>     'This equation has 1 real root.'
> ```

Python gave a "Private test cases failed" error. Where is my error?

```
def quadrtic(a,b,c):
d=b**2-4*a*c
if d<0:
    return "This equation has 2 complex roots."
elif d==1:
    return "This equation has 2 real roots."
elif d==0 or d==1:
    return "This equation has 1 real root."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` blocks should be

```
def quadrtic(a,b,c):
   d = b**2 - 4*a*c
   if d < 0:
       return "This equation has 2 complex roots."
   elif d > 0:
       return "This equation has 2 real roots."
   else:  # d == 0
       return "This equation has 1 real root."
```

The discriminant is very unlikely to be exactly `== 1`. For it to have two real roots, it just must be greater than 0, the discriminant can be any real number in this case (e.g. 4.2564)

Answer (score 0):

D=(b**2)-(4*a*c)

```
return('The discriminant is {0}.'.format(D))
```